# Control over random numbers in C#

Tags: c#

If I use two random numbers, how can I ensure that the first of these numbers generated is always larger than the second in order to present a subtraction or a divide quiz to the user?

Comment: Wouldn't be very random, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var max = 1000;
var rnd = new Random();
int a, b;
do
{
    a = rnd.Next(max);
    b = rnd.Next(max);
} while (a <= b);
```

You can use similar approach for more complex conditions too (for example if your task is to  generate 2 numbers that in sum give more than 100, etc).

You will have to make your code smarter if probability of random numbers satisfying your condition is so small that generation takes too much time but for this particular task this approach is good enough.

Answer (score 9):

You don't.

Just check which one is larger and present accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You generate the second random number and add it to the first one.

Comment: How about adding a random number to the first one and calling the result the second number?

Comment: Something along those lines. Not saying your initial answer is incorrect but this would likely be a working alternative :)

Comment: In this case the second number would be bigger than the first - which is the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: Not if you swap it ;) Thanks, I have updated - keeps getting better

Comment: That is right, if you swap it that would work. And if you would add a 12 and substract it again that would work as well. Or you could just compare both and present the bigger one in the first place - just like Oded said.

Comment: Yes, Oded had a better idea (this time) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate numbers like this (pseudocode): `(int)(a*rand()+b)` where a and b control the range and starting point of your random numbers.

If `a1=10, b1=1` for instance you get a range of `1-10`. With `a2=10` and `b2=11` you get numbers in the range `11-20`, which might be good for simple subtraction problems.